# checking recently connected external HDD properties

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem

I had an external hard disk and now it's not available. I connected that hard disk a lot of times to my laptop(Ubuntu 18.04). Is there any history in Ubuntu that help me to see my hard drive was either MBR or GPT? what about the file system(NTFS/FAT32/EXFAT/...)?